# unable to install npm packages node v5+

Tags: node.js, npm, cmd

> I am getting this error on npm install react-router-dom@next and npm install.  please help me with staging error encountered as show below

```
npm ERR! path C:\Github project\app1\node_modules\.staging
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Github project\app1\node_modules\.staging'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Github project\app1\node_modules\.staging'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\\Github project\\app1\\node_modules\\.staging\'',
```

Comment: Can you try deleting your `node_modules` folder and re-install the pacakges? `rm -rf node_modules`

Comment: still i am facing staging error . Can you tell why i get this error

Comment: Upgrade your `nodejs` version. You probably need `v6` and above now.